# PHPUnit, asserting html content

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

Which is the best way to assert with phpunit certain content in html strings?

In Zend applications there are a buch of assertions `assertQuery*` available. But if you are not in a Zend application? `assertXml*` doesn't look to be appropiate.

For instance, how would you assert that the tag `<div ... id="myId" ...>...</div>` exists in `$htmlString` taking into account that changing the position of the id attribute wouldn't fail the test?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest that you parse the HTML string using some library, and then use the library API for writing assertions.

There are lots of good HTML/XML parsers, for example:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

Using this you can access any desired node by using CSS selectors, xpath, etc, and you can check if an attribute exists independently of it's position.

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('div#elementId')->count());
```

You could also write a custom assertion that automates this process so that the assertion would be:

```
$this->assertHtmlContainsSelector($html, 'div#elementId');
```

Comment: That's a good approach. Considering your example with the `Crawler`, I was rather thinking of php built-in functions or pre-installed libraries. I will do it similarly with `DOMDocument`, i.e. `$doc = DOMDocument; $doc->loadHTML($html); $this->assertTrue((bool)$doc->getElementById('elementId'));`